# jQuery: Does toggleClass no longer have a duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, toggleclass

I can't get the `duration` setting on `toggleClass` to actually do anything.

I'm running jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.7.

jQuery's own example page of using duration doesn't work for me: http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/default.html

Clicking "Run Effect" literally does nothing in both Safari and Firefox 3.6 on Mac for me.

Anyone have some insight on this?

Comment: It appears to be broken in Firefox 3.6 and IE8 on Windows as well.

Comment: That demo is jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.16.  I would upgrade and see it it's still an issue.